# Series and Ticks not rendering for Date Axes in JQPlot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am currently working on graphing some performance data in JQPlot, but I can't get the actual data to render in the graph. Here is my js file contents,

```
var devserv111_read =[['7/22/2014 6:32 PM', 86.2570825582289],['7/22/2014 6:32     PM',57.5794327789494],['7/22/2014 6:32 PM', 19.2518887867064],['7/22/2014 6:32 PM', 62.34265069168],['7/22/2014 6:33 PM', 0],['7/22/2014 6:33 PM', 56.6436644845048]];
var plot_devserv111 = $.jqplot('chart_devserv111', [devserv111_read], {axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}}});
```

In the div chart_devserv111, a blank canvas shows up with appropriate y-axis ticks, but no points show up on the graph nor x-ticks. I was able to make the graph work with just the numerical data (not using dates for the x-axis).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include some plugins in order to draw your features. Especially the dateAxisRenderer plugin :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
```

Please see a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/9qyGL/2/), documentation [here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-dateAxisRenderer-js.html) and an example [here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/date-axes.php)

Comment: I have included the dateAxisRenderer, but I haven't tried the .min. Is there any reason why those would be different?

Comment: No the .min is only a minified version of the plugin. Do you have a good path for your plugin? Because regarding the symptoms you give (y-axis ok, works with numerical value...), the issue comes from the absence of the dateAxisRenderer plugin. (Try to comment the dateAxisRenderer loading in the fiddle created above, you should find yourself in the situation you have exposed)